# Jquery change class inside table

Tags: jquery

how can i change all `<pre>` classes attribute that are inside div?

i have tried the following:

```
 $('#tbl').find('.c1').find('#pre').attr("class","e");


<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div class="c1">
           <pre class= "d">
           ...
       </div>
   </td>

   <td>
       <div class="c1">
           <pre class="d">
           ...
       </div>
   </td>

 </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you.

Comment: `find('.pre')` # is for id

Comment: You must go through this http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
A great resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also generalize Adil's answer and in one line grab all the pre elements within a div with:

```
$('div').find('pre');
```

And to add a new class (say the class 'robots-are-cool')

```
$('div').find('pre').addClass('robots-are-cool');
```

is the simplest way. But jQuery also has ways to, say, add a class conditionally (http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to get the parent div with class `c1` and use the [Parent-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to get the `pre` tag. The [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) could be used to change the attribute in your case the class of elements returned by selector.

```
$('.c1 > pre').attr('a','b');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tbl > pre').attr("a","e");
```